# Animating label (NSTextField) horizontally

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

I have a `NSTextField` as a label, showing a string.
I want to animate this label from right to left, if the content of it is too large to be displayed at once.

I've done this with an `NSTimer` so far, it works, but it's just not a very good solution.
The labels are displayed in an `NSTextFieldCell`, in a Table View.
They often get out of sync, and I guess it's just eating up a lot of CPU/GPU resources.

Is there another way with `Core Animation` to do this?

I have tried it with layers, as you can see right here:
[CALayer and drawRect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035996/calayer-and-drawrect)

but I didn't get it working either.

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: did you try this...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266766/making-uitextview-scroll-programmatically

Comment: it's done with a timer, which is exactly what I want to avoid.

Comment: I am not master in Animations in cocoa. NSAnimation will do butttttt... it again uses timer calls implicitly.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Not sure if that's what I'm looking for...

Comment: Here's an implementation using UILabel. Looked at it briefly, but it looks like they're using Core Animation. https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel

Comment: @Dcritelli This is great, if it only was for Mac OS X now...

Comment: Yeah, that's why it was only a suggestion not an answer. Unfortunately, you'll have to look at how it's implemented and adapt it. CA should be cross platform. You just need to apply it to the App Kit control instead of the UIKit one. Easier said than done, I know.

Comment: @Dcritelli I will, if there really are no other sample code projects or simpler solutions. It has about 900 lines of code, this would take some time. Especially not pleasing for such a simple control.

Comment: Thanks, I used the timer approach to animate text writing from top to bottom.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply animate the position of NSTextField with animator like

```
[[textField animator] setFrameOrigin:NSMakePoint(x,y)];
```

you can also embed it in "CATrancation" code like this:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut]];
[[textField animator] setFrameOrigin:NSMakePoint(x,y)];
[CATransaction commit];
```

if you need animation delegate, you can use CABasicAnimation

```
CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animation];
animation.delegate = self;
NSDictionary *animations = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:animation,@"frameOrigin",nil]; 
[textField setAnimations:animations];
[[textField animator] setFrameOrigin:NSMakePoint(x,y)];
```

Delegate methods are

```
- (void)animationDidStart:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation;
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag;
```

If you need to mask  your text field, just embed it in other NSView.

Comment: This is not really what I'm looking for. This set's the position of the whole label. I want to display an image beside it, they would overlap.

Comment: Then you can add the code above on a UIView that contains the label. The label won't go out of the view so it acts as a "margin". Also bringSubviewToFront would prevent the image to be overlapped.

Comment: @k20 Thanks, I think this will actually do it!

Comment: @NSAddict you are very welcome, I added it as an answer just in case someone else wants to do the same as you

Answer (score 1):

First, animate the label using one of the functions offered in the other answers.
 Then, if you want to display another view on the sides without overlapping, you can:

- Insert the label in a subview with the limits you wish
- Use bringSubviewtoFront: or sendSubviewToBack: to make sure your label stays in the back